# Lost Focus and GotFocus in c++

Tags: c++, winapi, native

How do you add code to these events for native c++?

I couldn't find a `WM_LOSTFOCUS` OR `WM_GOTFOCUS`; I only found `WM_SETFOCUS`. I need code to happen when my window loses focus, and regains it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

JUST BEFORE your window loses focus it will be sent: `WM_KILLFOCUS`
AFTER your window gains focus, it will be sent: `WM_SETFOCUS`

Sending a WM_SETFOCUS message does not set the focus. You need to call SetFocus for that.

Comment: Sending WM_SETFOCUS does not set the focus. You need to call the SetFocus function.

Answer (score 3):

For an edit control, `WM_KILLFOCUS` won't work.

Took me too long to figure out that I needed [EN_KILLFOCUS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761682%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Hopefully saves the next guy some time.

Answer (score 2):

The message you're looking for is WM_KILLFOCUS

Answer (score 0):

You may consider **WM_ACTIVATE** as well. When main window is concerned, activation message could be the only solution.